# How do I create an empty minecraft world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My friends and I want to create an adventure map, so I want to have a empty Minecraft Craftbukkit server map to start with, so there will be nothing other than the things I want to put into the map. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Every block has to be placed against another block, so you can't do anything at all with a completely empty world. You need to define empty.

Comment: Okay. At least one block on the map?

Comment: Simple then: Mine every block but one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With bukkit there are plugins that change the world generation to make the world flat, for example:

http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/wgen-flatlands-v0-1-makes-a-flat-world-860.20888/

http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/wgen-hugetractsofland-0-1-generate-a-flat-world-using-any-block-1060.28662/

You can also search http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/?category=world-generators for different types of world generators.

Note: I have not tried either of them.

Answer (score 7):

I would have to say that you just go into the `server.properties` file and edit it to be `super-flat` instead of `default`. The drawback to that is that you will not be able to go underground since it is only 3 blocks away from the 1 layer of bedrock.

Comment: Only "level-type=flat" works. There is not "super-flat" according to https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Server.properties#Java_Edition_3 .  "flat" allows you to generate four layers (so not empty/one-block-only world). I have one answer (use SinglePlayer game, generate world named "world" and copy that world directory to the server folder) but need 10 reputation points to be able to add it :-).

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean empty? They're all empty. If you mean flat or featureless, all you can do, in the unlikely event of finding a seed that would create a world like that, is create one as normal, play it, fly around for a good while in all directions to get chunks generated, then use MCEdit to flatten it. But new chunks will always be generated as normal.

Comment: You could just [make it flat yourself](http://3d.xkcd.com/861/).

Comment: @fredley -- +1 for using the 3D version.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MCEdit to create a world and create chunks in it that are empty except for a layer of bedrock.

Comment: Wow 9 hours to mention this. But yea, You can make a flat empty map in MCEdit very easily.

Comment: Because the OP is in a different time zone I would imagine.

Answer (score 3):

Make a superflat world out of air blocks. Make sure you have villages on, and you have an (almost) emtpy world.

Comment: Seems to be the best way to do this in vanilla. You could probably also make an entirely empty world and use mods/MCEdit/hex editors/whatever to create a single block from nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You know, I was wondering the exact same thing. I figured out if you make superflat just one layer of tnt then ignite it, it will blow up everything. BUT be sure you put a piece of
bedrock down first. Also the server may crash or get really laggy. But you can also use World Edit to clear out the world.

Comment: wool would make more sense, but that's an awesome idea if you don't have world edit.

Answer (score 3):

make a superflat world with only one layer of sand.  The moment you put a block down, the sand will fall into the void leaving just the block you placed.

Comment: Intriguing answer.  I wonder how bad it would lag from all the sand falling.  Would be fun to watch.

Answer (score 2):

Set `generator-settings=1;0;1` and `level-type=FLAT` and `gamemode=1` in the `server.properties`. Note this would will have no blocks at all. As you are in creative mode fly to y: 0 (press F3 to see coords). Note: You will start dropping quickly so be ready. Install the WorldEdit plugin from bukkit plugins and type `//pos1` then move a little and type `//pos2` and `//set stone` or whatever block you want.

In later versions, you could use `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:stone` and not have to install WorldEdit.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the DemonicMushy's comment on his question, I think he means a map with no blocks at all. Try looking for maps such as [this one](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/804298-blank-void-map/) and importing them into multiplayer. 3000x3000 blocks of void. Of course, if you meant a map that isn't void, use the superflat world option when creating a singleplayer world and import it to multiplayer to build together.

Answer (score -1):

Download the map "SKY BLOCK" and clear it all out. There's only 30 blocks or so and then the map is completely empty.

Comment: Not completely empty. There's normal terrain generated if you go far (not very far) enough.